# Federal Holiday Calendar Service

Tags: data.gov, api, calendar

Looking for an open Federal / Holiday Calendar service to show business hours of banking or credit related businesses.

I've requested this here:

- https://explore.data.gov/nominate/2930

and I've seen paid services here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934/national-holiday-web-service

but looking for an open data solution

Comment: Is this not acceptable? http://archive.opm.gov/Operating_Status_Schedules/fedhol/2014.asp

Comment: Ah, nevermind - just saw that you're looking for a service instead of just the data.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things that might be helpful.

- [Federal holidays through 2020](http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays)
- [Current status](http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/current-status/) with [XML](http://www.opm.gov/xml/operatingstatus.xml) and [RSS feeds](http://www.opm.gov/rss/operatingstatus.atom)

Alerts and hurricane warnings are also listed.